# Accelerating for loops with list methods in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iteration

I have for loops in python that iterates nearly 2.5 million times and it's taking so much time to get a result. In JS I can make this happen in nearly 1 second but Python does it in 6 seconds on my computer. I must use Python in this case. Here is the code:

```
            for i in xrange(k,p,2):
                arx = process[i]
                ary = process[i+1]
                for j in xrange(7,-1,-1):
                    nx = arx + dirf[j]
                    ny = ary + dirg[j]
                    ind = ny*w+nx
                    if data[ind] == e[j]:       
                        process[c]=nx
                        c=c+1
                        process[c]=ny
                        c=c+1
                        matrix[ind]=1
```

Here is some lists from code:
`process = [None] * (11000*4)` it's items will be replaced with integers after it's assignment.

```
dirf = [-1,0,1,-1,1,-1,0,1]
dirg = [1,1,1,0,0,-1,-1,-1]
e = [9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

the data list is consists of 'r' informations from pixels of an rgba image.
`data = imgobj.getdata(0)`

How can I boost this. What am I doing wrong? Is there any other approaches about for loops? Thanks.

Comment: it takes 34.9 *milliseconds* to iterate 2.5million times  on my machine (it is slow but it is not 6 seconds slow).

Comment: it's fast but just when use it without the assignments below. I have to work with them.

Comment: Have you tried numba http://numba.pydata.org/ to speed up your python?

Comment: If you have to work with them; you should ask about them: what do they do? What is the purpose? Here's a good getting-started reference: [How to optimize for speed](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/performance.html)

Comment: I'm working with image data and I think what they do is obvious. I have arrays and am processing datas from these arrays then creating new arrays.

Comment: libraries like numba, numerical python (http://www.numpy.org/), or cython (http://cython.org/) will give you some options to improve performance

Comment: @paradoksumsu can you show more of the code? how are the lists `process` , `dirf`, `dirg` , `data` , `e` defined?

Comment: @AnandSKumar they are added now.

Comment: @paradoksumsu No, I mean in code how are they defined, if the loop you are wishing to optimize inside a function? are process,dirf, etc created inside the function?

Comment: @AnandSKumar http://paste.ubuntu.com/11928279/ you can see whole code in here. the slow part is between 68 and 82nd lines.

Comment: The way you are timing it may skew things - taking `time.time()` before and after and subtracting is *not* best practice; instead, use the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module to time the whole script, and use [profiling](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) to get detailed information about what is slowing it down. I can't quite follow what your pastebin'd code is doing, but it does look like numpy would be a good option - both for speed and readability.

Comment: Also, consider that questions about performance issues and general best practice in otherwise working code might be better asked on [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score -3):

Here are a few suggestions for improving your code:

That inner xrange is being used a lot: what if you made that a regular list and just did something like this:

```
inner = range(7,-1,-1) # make the actual list
for(a,b,c): #first for
    #stuff
    for i in inner # reference an actual list and not the generator
```

Evidence :

```
n = range(7,-1,-1)
def one():
    z = 0
    for k in xrange(100):
        for i in n:
            z+=1

def two():
    z = 0
    for k in xrange(100):
        for i in xrange(7,-1,-1):
            z+=1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print("one:")
    print(timeit.timeit("one()",number=1000000 ,setup="from __main__ import one"))
    print("two:")
    print(timeit.timeit("two()",number=1000000 ,setup="from __main__ import two"))

"result" 
one:
37.798637867
two:
63.5098838806
```

If the code I wrote is comparable, it would appear to indicate that referencing the inner list and not generating really speeds it up.
[edit] referencing local variable is faster than accessing global.
so if this is correct place the list definition as close to the loop as possible without having it generate every time.

You are also changing process twice. If it's not needed, just choose one.

As you mentioned in the comments, you say you're working with images. I am not sure if the following is relevant, but perhaps you could use openCV, which has a Python API to C code. That might speed it up. As others have mentioned: numpy and your own cython extensions will speed this up considerably.

Comment: Your set of timings for assignments doesn't show a speedup of a tenth of a second - that `e-08` at the end means the difference is actually roughly *a nanosecond*. Your timings for not calling `xrange` every time around the loop gives a speedup of (63.5 - 37.8)/100,000 seconds which is [just under 26 microseconds](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2863.5+-+37.8%29%2F1000000+seconds). Even in a critical inner loop, these types of microoptimisations are likely to have an utterly negligible effect on the overall running time.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I forgot to read the exponent, will remove that section

Comment: The bit you've left in is nearly as bad, though, since a) you didn't average the timing across the number of passes, and b) the change you're testing against affects the whole outer loop once. Even if OPs outer loop iterates quite a bit more than your example, you've provided evidence that they might save, at the very most, a few milliseconds off their six second run time.